# Why is the Run option disabled on PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I observed that on a new project the *Run* option is disabled and I expected to be able to run a script without having to manually add a configuration for it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't run without a configuration, however temporary configuration can be created automatically if you use **Run** context menu option in the script editor.

Comment: This is how I usually did it, but for this project the only options that are enables in the context menu are `Create/Run/Debug "Doctests in open"`.

Comment: It depends on the project and on the file contents, maybe you need to create a configuration first for this type of project.

Comment: Might be worth saying what a configuration is and how to create it.

Answer (score 68):

If you're creating a project from existing source:
 and
 If the existing source directory contains a lot of data/files:

- the Run option (and others, assumably) are disabled until PyCharm is finished indexing the contents in the project.  You'll see a progress bar in the lower-right-hand corner.

You can speed this up by **right-clicking on folders and selecting "Mark directory as..." -> "Excluded" if they aren't to be indexed.**

Comment: +1, in addition the first time I ran PyCharm using my Anaconda install it had to index all the Anaconda libraries, that takes a few minutes potentially.

Comment: By far the best explanation. If you use invalidate cache and restart, pycharm still does the fresh indexing. Till the details are not indexed under the project, you will not get code completion and run option in pycharm. Thanks Jordan for the answer.

Answer (score 46):

Right click inside your main file & then you get Run option!

Comment: Thank you. But why in the world would the Run button that can be seen be dim, but right clicking gives you a working Run button and magically enables the dim Run button?

Comment: This worked for ma as well (the top left also became green thereafter). An explanation would be great!

Comment: @Jim probably it sets the file to run in the settings (ctrl+alt+s>search for interpreter). it has to know which file gets run when you press run.

Answer (score 10):

I solved it just by right clicking on the .py file and clicking 'run'. After this the run button appeared enabled!

Answer (score 7):

If the project folder contains a lot of files then the indexing process can take a long time. So you might need to wait before the Run button appears.

Comment: Yea if it says it's indexing you just have to wait... (This was my problem, in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Select drop down menu to the left of the run button at the top right, select Edit configurations, expand defaults on the left, select whatever you were working on (if python, select python). Then click OK. Dialogue will close. Make sure the file that you want to run is on top. Hit ctrl+shift+F10 to run. The run button should be enabled again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your file name in drop down menu on top right corner.
2. Then go to `edit configurations`.
3. Next the Run/Debug Configurations dialog box will be open.
4. Then under execution, uncheck Run with Python console
5. Apply> Ok

Then you will get the Run window again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when you have newly setup your pycharm environment, it starts to index the scripts. You will see something like `Indexing...` at the bottom of the window. Once it is complete you can `right click` and select `Run`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all answers, and none worked for me. What did work is:

1.) open another repository / project

- File > Open > `select project` > OK

2.) If you have the pop-up to choose "This Window or "New Window", chose "This Window"

3.) Open the repository / project that **had the greyed out run button**

4.) It should be green by now