# 'Process finished with exit code 0' . No output in print()

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using `Pycharm 3.7`. Very basic code.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 15, 33, 156]
print(myList)
b = 0
print(b)
```

Though Pycharm gives no output. Only `Process finished with exit code 0`
And I don't understand why. Yesterday I was working in Pycharm and everything was fine.

[image: Print screen of a pycharm code]

Comment: The file you're running is `example_1.py` not `exercises.py` that has the `print`.

Comment: Also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364483

Answer (score 1):

right click anywhere in the page you are at, and click `Run "Page_name"` to run that page and set the current page-to-run to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the correct file. You are running example_1.py instead of exercises.py

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm runs the example_1.py. You need to run your own file which is exercises.py